# What happens if I choose "Install Ubuntu alongside archlinux" during installation guide?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

So I just installed Ubuntu in a machine that already had Archlinux on a partition.

During the installation, I was presented an "`Install Ubuntu alongside Archlinux`" option which I had to ignore because I was not sure how exactly it would affect my Archlinux partition.

I'd be thankful if someone here can tell me how Ubuntu proceeds about installation in that scenario (does it share the partition with Archlinux in some way? is it even safe?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu will create it's own partitions. Normally, Archlinux is safe; however, backing up data is always recommended. Weird things can happen.

I would recommend resizing the partitions yourself then tell the ubuntu installer to use free space to install.